# symfony2 validation inheritance

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have one parent entity that has multiple child entities that inherit its methods. When comes the time to validate forms i have no idea how NOT to repeat each parent fields validation constraints.

Here is some code:

```
#validation.yml
Dir\Entity\Parent:
    properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: {message: 'name.empty'}

Dir\Entity\Child1:
    properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: {message: 'name.empty'}
        age:
          - NotBlank: {message: 'age.empty'}

Dir\Entity\Child2:
    properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: {message: 'name.empty'}
        title:
          - NotBlank: {message: 'title.empty'}
```

As you can see, the name property is coming back again and again in the child constraint. Is there any way to include the parent constraint directly in the childs one so i won't have to repeat parent constraints modifications?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Yokoloko i forget sometimes to give solutions. Here's what I've done:

I've created a constraint validation for the parent so i won't have to reproduce the code everytime i create a child. Therefore i only focus on child's fields when necessary.

Here's what inspired me http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Let me know if you need additional details